# Problem in understanding the meaning of a quantified conditional statement based on the position of the negation operator.

Tags: predicate-logic, quantifiers

Let the universe of discourse be the set of all human beings. $M(x)$ is an open statement which stands for "x is a man" and $B(x)$ stands for "x has black hair".

I have problem understanding how the statement 
$\neg(\forall x)(M(x) \rightarrow B(x))$ is different in meaning from $(\forall x)\neg(M(x)\rightarrow B(x))$ in meaning.

Is my understanding correct if I say statement 1 means not every man has black hair and statement 2 means: NO MAN (not human beings) has black hair?

Comment: Have you tried rewriting them in English? The second starts "For all men ..." and I would begin a sentence for the first one with "There is a man ..." to deal with the "not for all".

Comment: The edit changes what I suggest the sentences say but not the recommendation to say it in English.

Comment: Yes I have and would I be right in saying statement 1 means: not every man has black hair and statement 2 means: NO MAN has black hair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first statement means that it is not true that every man has black hair

The second statement is equivalent to $\forall x (M(x) \land \neg H(x))$ and thus means that everything in the domain is a man and does not have black hair

I asume you can see the difference now ...

Comment: Would I be right in saying statement 1 means: not every man has black hair and statement 2 means: NO MAN (not human beings) has black hair?

Comment: Statement two is actually a good but stronger than that: *nothing* has black hair under statement two

Comment: I mean no argument. Only trying to understand it fully. But isn't it the case that statement 2 is logically equivalent to $(\forall x)(\neg M(x) \vee B(x))$?

Comment: @mainulislam No. $\forall x \ \neg (M(x) \rightarrow H(x))$ is equivalent to $\forall x \ \neg (\neg M(x) \lor H(x))$ and thus to $\forall x (M(x) \land \neg H(x))$